# onCreateOptionsMenu not being called on FragmentActivity when run on phone version

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, fragment

I create an app that supports both phone and tablet version so i use the android-support-v4.jar library. My activity extends the FragmentActivity and override the onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu). This works fine on tablet, the onCreateOptionsMenu being called correctly but it doesn't work on phone, onCreateOptionsMenu never get called. How to resolve this?

Note: i use `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="12"/>` on Manifest file.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should consider from your `Fragment` code:

1) Implementing `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`

2) Calling `setHasOptionsMenu`

3) And also implementing `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

Then you will be ok on both the phone and tablet.

Comment: It's very easy to forget to call setHasOptionsMenu.

Comment: Another call worth mentioning in addition to the ones PJL said: 

4) setMenuVisibility(true);

Comment: @Buffalo I've been grinding on this for hours, thanks man, `setMenuVisibility()` did the trick.