# onCreateOptionsMenu not getting called inside the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

onCreateOptionsMenu method is never called even though I have done all the steps from other similar questions (like this one: [Menu inside fragment not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654793/menu-inside-fragment-not-getting-called);
and this: [onCreateOptionsMenu not being called on FragmentActivity when run on phone version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936842/oncreateoptionsmenu-not-being-called-on-fragmentactivity-when-run-on-phone-versi))

1) I call setHasOptionsMenu(true) in onCreate method of the Fragment

2) I override onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) methd like this

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main,  menu);
}
```

[ 3) And also I dp implement onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) ]

WTH?

P.S. I am using android-support-v4.jar.

P.P.S @[Philipp Jahoda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1590502/philipp-jahoda), I do implement onCreateOptionsMenu(...) in a Fragment's hosting Activity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is solved.

I am using ActionBarSherlock, but my fragment class was extending "Fragment" class instead of "SherlockFragment". So onCreateOptionsMenu method was not getting called.

That simple..