# Editing the ActionBar with a FragmentActivity that implements ActionBar.TabListener

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-actionbar

In my android app, I am trying to add icons to the ActionBar in my FragmentActivity; however, it remains blank.

I want to actionbar to have two icons from block.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

      tools:context=".SetupActivity" >



    <item android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
          app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:orderInCategory="200"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I am trying to follow this: [onCreateOptionsMenu not being called on FragmentActivity when run on phone version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936842/oncreateoptionsmenu-not-being-called-on-fragmentactivity-when-run-on-phone-versi)

Here is my BlockActivity class which extends FragmentActivity. I am unsure why the ActionBar is unable to be edited in spite of having the onCreateOptionsMenu method.

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;


// 



/**
 * Created by Spicycurryman on 6/17/14.
 */
public  class BlockActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = {"Installed", "System", "Custom"};

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.block_apps);


        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }

    //Here is onCreateOptionsMenu method that should work

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);
        return true;
    }





    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }




}
```

Should onCreateOptionsMenu be implemented in the separate Fragments?

Answer (score 0):

You did not call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` inside you `onCreateOptionsMenu` method so thats why  it remains blank.

**solution:**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

add this as well:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

add the action as well:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_overflow) {
        return true;
    } else if(id == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: @XiJiaopin editted add the above code to your actovoity

Comment: It still has not shown up is the problem still in onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: @XiJiaopin i dont think so but try ti add the optionitems selected. and update me, see edit above

Comment: I apologize for the trouble but the action bar icons still won't display

Comment: @XiJiaopin can you post a picture what it look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56169/discussion-between-xijiaopin-and-rod-algonquin).