# ActionBar icons won't show up for FragmentActivity despite setHasOptionsMenu(true)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-actionbar

In my android app, I am trying to add icons to the ActionBar in my FragmentActivity; however, it remains blank. Essentially I have a FragmentActivity with separate Fragments which are scrollable tabs like this:

[image]

I want to actionbar to have two icons from block.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

      tools:context=".SetupActivity" >



    <item android:id="@+id/action_overflow"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
          app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:orderInCategory="200"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

I want it to look something like this:

[image]

I am trying to follow this: [onCreateOptionsMenu not being called on FragmentActivity when run on phone version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936842/oncreateoptionsmenu-not-being-called-on-fragmentactivity-when-run-on-phone-versi)

and this  https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/ActionBar-Tabs-with-Fragments

Here is my BlockActivity class which extends FragmentActivity. I am unsure why the ActionBar is unable to be edited in spite of having the onCreateOptionsMenu method.

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import info.androidhive.tabsswipe.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;


// Find out about the default file template warning



/**
 * Created by Spicycurryman on 6/17/14.
 */
public  class BlockActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {



    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = {"Installed", "System", "Custom"};

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.block_apps);


        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.block, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_overflow) {
            return true;
        } else if(id == R.id.action_search) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }





    }
```

I have tried everything from inflating from the Fragments to doing it from the FragmentActivity and everything in between not sure what to do now...

Comment: Is your ActionBar showing at all? What is th theme that you have applied to your Activity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of extending `FragmentActivity`, extend `ActionBarActivity`.

`ActionBarActivity` has everything what `FragmentActivity` has and allows you to access easily to your `ActionBar` by calling `getActionBar()` or `getSupportActionBar()` for support version.

You can check more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html).

Don't forget to set the activity theme to Theme.AppCompat or a similar theme, and it will work.

Comment: `ActionBarActivity` is now deprecated. I use `AppCompatActivity` in its place. It does the job and one can use `getSupportActionBar()` to access it in activity.

Answer (score -1):

use these theams for action bar might be it solve your problem :)

Theme.Holo for a "dark" theme
Theme.Holo.Light for a "light" theme

Comment: Plus i made sure that the icons would be different colors than action bar